# get URL in php IN INCLUDE FILE

Tags: php, url, include

i have some problem i try to get the uri in php.

I'm using:

```
 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

It works just fine if i do it in the index.php, but, i NEED to get the url in a include file, but, when i do it, it takes the FILE adress, i mean, it shows something like this

adress bar: www.webpage.com/index.php

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  output:  webpage/includefile.php

I am explaining myself here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us some context? How are you using this code? and How are you including it into the page?

Answer (score 1):

How are you including the file? If it's being included via an HTTP reference then it's actually being served as a page and the functionality you are seeing is correct. If the include path is a local file, you shouldn't be seeing this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Found this whilst trying to solve the same issue.
My solution that worked is to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
This worked well in that it also included the parameters (e.g. ?this=that&foo=bar)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somewhere in your code (or in another include file) the value is overwritten.